# Perform addition operation in Laravel updateOrCreate

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i'm working on a ecommerce project and i have an issue in the cart system. so, the user can add product to cart by its price and if the user add the same product again, the price (in the cart) should accumulated. for example, i add an apple to cart for $20, then i add it again for $10, the price should be $30 right now.

i tried to do this

```
$cart = Cart::updateOrCreate(
            ['order_id' => $order->id, 'product_id' => $request->product_id],
            ['price' => DB::raw("price + $request->price")]
);
```

it works fine to update price from existing cart model, but the price is always null in database if the new cart model is created. do you guys have any suggestions to fix this problem? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `IFNULL()` in your raw query

```
$cart = Cart::updateOrCreate(
            ['order_id' => $order->id, 'product_id' => $request->product_id],
            ['price' => DB::raw("IFNULL(price, 0) + $request->price")]
);
```

`IFNULL(field, 0)` will return 0 if the field is NULL and the value if not.

Comment: it works, thank you very much :)